# Disable Real Time Change In View Mode

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, iframe

I have a webserver that serves one webpage which has an embedded Excel document in an iframe.

When I view this webpage with a user who has viewing permissions for the embedded Excel link, the webpage opens with a popup on the right that says:

> You are seeing real time changes in View Mode

And just like the popup mentions, if someone is editing the actual file or even viewing it, you can see this action in real time as it is happening.

I want to view the page as it was when loaded and if I need to see any changes I would do it by just refreshing the frame.

How can I disable real time changes when I serve the page in a iframe like this?

Comment: See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/embed-your-excel-workbook-on-your-web-page-or-blog-from-sharepoint-or-onedrive-for-business-7af74ce6-e8a0-48ac-ba3b-a1dd627b7773

This is expected behavior, the Excel for the web iframe embed parameters do not include an option to disable real-time updates.